# getting NaN error when getting data from a table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a NaN error when I run this code. I have a cell in a table that I am getting the data from.

I am trying to add up the values in a column. Right now the table has two rows, the first row has 28.55 and the second row has 30.00.

When the first alert shows its 28.55, when the second shows it 30.0. When the third alert shows the sum is NaN. How do I make the conversion so it can sum correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
function changeBalance() {

var sum = 0;

$("td.pmt").each(function() {
payment = $(this);
alert(payment.html());

sum += parseFloat(payment.val());


});      
alert(sum);
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;   

}
```

Comment: RTFM ~ [*"The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`"*](http://api.jquery.com/val/). I'd probably go with `.text()`

Comment: @Phil So basically, `sum += parseFloat(payment.html())` instead. Why so many downvotes, though?

Comment: @gengkev I'd probably go with `.text()` instead of `.html()`, just to be on the safe side. I don't know why so many downvotes, lack of research effort perhaps?

Comment: @ja11946 the problem is you are attempting to do a mathematical operation on something that is not a number. You need to cast/convert it to a number first, e.g. what gengkev showed

Comment: @CrayonViolent OP is already *casting* it to a number. It's just that `.val()` will return an empty string for non-form-control elements

Comment: @Phil, so, show me in the manual where it says that `.val()` *can't* be used for this? As I said, "primarily used for" != "can't be used for anything else".

Comment: @CrayonViolent which is why I said to use `.text()` instead

Comment: Everyone, thank you for the help. Changing to text() from val() did the trick. thanks for the support also, I was feeling a little gun shy on asking questions, however your support has change that. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Its happened because there should be string value and you trying to add with integer variable.

That's why it will return NaN(**Not a Number**)

try this before add

```
if(!isNaN(payment.val()) && payment.val()!='')
 {
    sum += parseFloat(payment.val());
 }
```

Hope it will help out you....['}